# assertDictEqual with pandas DF

Tags: python, python-unittest, assert

I need to combine assertDictEqual with pandas.testing.assert_frame_equal.
let's assume I have the following functions:

```
def function_to_test():
    data = {'Name': ['Tom', 'Joseph'], 'Age': [20, 21]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    return {"key_first_level": {"key_second_level": df}} 


def test_function_to_test():
    data = {'Name': ['Tom', 'Joseph'], 'Age': [20, 21]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    expected_dict = {"key_first_level": {"key_second_level": df}}
    actual_dict = function_to_test()
    self.assertDictEqual(expected_dict, actual_dict)
```

The problem with assertDictEqual on test_function_to_test when it tries to compare the pd df, it compares the df's by address and not by df's values. I'm looking for classic solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `assertDictEqual` method is comparing the 2 `dict`s using the `!=` operator. While the `dict` type returns a single `True/False` for the `!=` and `==` operations, `DataFrame` returns `True/False` for every value in the table and that is what actually causing the error `ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()`. For `DataFrame` to return a single `True/False` value, compare unsing [equals](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.equals.html) method.

One way to overcome this is by creating some kind of a `Compare` class with a custome comparation logic and wrap the `DataFrame` instance with it. This way, when the `DataFrame` will be compared, it will do this using the logic implemented in the `Compare` class.

```
import unittest
from typing import Any

import pandas as pd


class CompareDataFrames:
    def __init__(self, data_frame: pd.DataFrame):
        self.data_frame = data_frame

    def __eq__(self, other: Any) -> bool:
        return isinstance(other, pd.DataFrame) and self.data_frame.equals(other)


def function_to_test():
    data = {'Name': ['Tom', 'Joseph'], 'Age': [20, 21]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    return {"key_first_level": {"key_second_level": df}}


class TestStringMethods(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_function_to_test(self):
        data = {'Name': ['Tom', 'Joseph'], 'Age': [20, 21]}
        df = pd.DataFrame(data)
        expected_dict = {"key_first_level": {"key_second_level": CompareDataFrames(df)}}
        actual_dict = function_to_test()
        self.assertDictEqual(expected_dict, actual_dict)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: I still getting this error `ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().` , maybe because the return df isn't instance of `CompareDataFrames` and just the expected df?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `return df`, where is the df returned from? The code I provided above fixes this error for the reference code. How do you produce this error?

Comment: return df = the df inside actual_dict

Comment: The code I provided above fixes this error. How do you produce this error?